# PHP global variables

Tags: php

Why does the following result in an error message? (it is declared inside a function in PHP by the way; $a and $b are alphabetic values, not numeric)

```
global $pre[''.$a.''], $predis[''.$b.''];

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in ...
```

Comment: Just FYI, don't do `$pre[''.$a.'']`, just do `$pre[$a]`.

Comment: @Rocket even if it is alphabetical and not numeric (ex: "abc" and not "123")?

Comment: Yes that is correct you don't need the `''` even with a non-numeric key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
global $pre, $predis;
```

Then use `$pre` and `$predis` how you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can't make array index global. In this case, only `$pre` and `$predis` may be global and you can use their contents as you need:

```
global $pre, $predis;
```

Answer (score 6):

I  may be mistaken, but I believe you cannot selectively use keys as globals. You would have to do

```
global $pre, $predis;
```

and then use the keys.

The problem lies in that while the variables `$pre` and `$predis` have unique identifiers, the keys are only identified in reference to their variables, such that `$var1['key'] != $var2['key']`. There is no way to assign that specific key to an identifier while making it global, at least in one step. You could however, use an intermediate variable, like

```
$prekey = $pre['key'];
global $prekey;
```